# How many eggs should you buy from each shop?

Tags: linear-algebra

You need to purchase a total of 100 eggs from 3 shops with a minimum of 1 egg from each shop in such a way that you spend exactly `100$`. The first shop sells each egg for `5 cents`, the second shop sells each egg for `1$` and the third shop sells each egg for `5$`. How many eggs should you buy from each shop?

To solve the above, I am getting only 2 equations:

```
0.05x + y + 5z = 100
x + y + z =100 ; x + y + z >=3
```

Is it even possible to solve a 3 variable system with 2 equations?

Comment: A 3-variable, 2-equation linear system will always have infinitely many solutions (this is true of any system of linear equations with more variables than equations).

Comment: Perhaps, $x,y,z\in\Bbb N$ is the third equation

Comment: @GregMartin: That is not quite correct. For example, the system $$x + y + z = 1$$ $$2x + 2y + 2z = 4$$ has no solutions.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani very good point (I erred by thinking of the homogeneous case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a 3 variable system with 2 equations can be solved but it will have infinitely many solutions if it has any solutions. It is also possible that it is not solvable. But in your case the system is solvable. But in your context only solutions with $x,y,z \ge 0$ and $x,y,z \in \mathbb Z$ make sense. You can solve the system by using Gauß algorithm or basic manipulations. For example we can subtract the second from the first equation to get
$$-0.95x +4z =0 \Leftrightarrow 0.95x=4z \Leftrightarrow x = \frac{80}{19} z$$
Plugging that in to the second equation we obtain
$$ \frac{80}{19} z+y+z = 100 \Leftrightarrow y= 100 - \frac{99}{19} z$$
So the general solution is
$$(x,y,z) = ( \frac{80}{19} z, 100 - \frac{99}{19} z, z)$$
which is infinitely many solutions as you can choose your $z$ like you want it. But we now have to make sure, that all three components are integers. For that we have only one chance, namely $z$ has to be a multiple of 19. Otherwise the fractions will not give integer values (because they are already reduced and $19$ is a prime number with $80$ and $99$ not being divisible by it). So we can check:

$z=0$ is impossible - we have to buy at least one egg at the third shop

$z=19$ gives $(x,y,z) = (80, 1, 19)$ which is a good solution.

$z=38$ would already give a negative $y$-value as would all bigger multiples of $19$. Therefore the solution is $(80, 1, 19)$.